# Class array | How to transform to data frame

Tags: r

I'm learning R.

I've put a set of databases together into one.

```
Data <- smartbind(2014, 2015, 2016)
table(Data$year, useNA=c("always")
```

I have selected numeric variable `Data$x` and grouped by  numeric `Data$year` as follows

```
a <- tapply(Data$x, Data$year, summary)
```

and results as follows when I use `print(a)`

```
c(1, 10, 4, 15, ...)
c(29, 2, 3, 7, ...)
c(2, 7, 4, 8,...)
```

And this form of array does not work with the following code to extract and summarize information from the first and third quartiles, and median

```
xdata <- as.data.frame(rbind(x2014 <- c(2014, a[["2014"]][["1st Qu."]], 
         a[["2014"]][["Median"]], a[["2014"]][["3rd Qu."]]),
x2015 <- c(2015, a["2015", "1st Qu."], a[["2015"]][["Median"]], 
          a[["2015"]][["3rd Qu."]]), 
x2016 <- c(2016, a[["2016"]][["1st Qu."]], a[["2016"]][["Median"]], 
         a[["2016"]][["3rd Qu."]])` 
colnames(losstroke) <- c("Year", "Q1", "Median", "Q3") 
rm(a, x2014, x2015, x2016)`
```

how can I solve it?
Would I have to convert the array `a` to a data frame? How could I do that?

Comment: where is `smartbind()` from?

Comment: "Data <- smartbind(2014, 2015, 2016)"
# 2014, 2015, 2016 are databases containing the variables I have described.

Comment: But smartbind is a function which isn't in base R; so it's non standard.  If others are to understand you should say which package it came from (with some detective work I'm guessing gtools but I can't be sure).  Anyway, R won't allow data frames with the names 2014, 2015 and 2016 so that might be your starting point of a problem.  More generally, I suggest you try to reframe your question in a way that abstracts away from your particular data issues, which will help you get to the essence of it (and maybe answer it yourself), and certainly help better answers.  Try a reproducible example.

Comment: I get it. Thanks!